# Difference between using else if and just if conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, merge, mergesort

I was creating a merge sort algorithm and came across an issue. After like 30 minutes I replaced my if statements with else if, and this fixed my problem. Can anyone explain to me why this is? Also, what is the best way to write merge algorithms? I feel mine took a while to write and so I'm looking for ways I can improve my own efficiency.

Here's the code:

```
  public static void merge( int[] a, int[] b, int[] result )
    { int one = 0; 
      int two = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

          if(one < a.length && two < b.length){
              if (a[one] < b[two]){
              result[i] = a[one];
              one++;
              }
             else {result[i] = b[two];
             two++;
             }
          }

          else if(one < a.length && two >= b.length){
              result[i] = a[one];
             one++;
             }

          else if(two < b.length && one >= a.length){
              result[i] = b[two];
              two++;     }
```

I used this array to do it: { 1, 4, 3, 9, 6, 2, 3, 7, 10 }. Using the if statements by themselves were fine until it had to sort the last two elements. My result displayed 1,2,3,3,4,6,7,10,10 and missed out on the 9. Changing the if statements to else if fixed the sorting.

Comment: This would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger; then you could see for yourself what the difference is.

Comment: `else if` will only run if the preceding condition failed to evaluate to `$True`. `if` will run once it is hit. Checking additional conditions needlessly will add processing time to your program. This is true for most, if not all, languages which incorporate `if`/`then`/`else` logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several separate `if`s, more than one of their conditional blocks can be executed, even if their conditions themselves seem to prevent that.
In contrast to that, using a chain of `else if` guarantees that only one conditional block will be executed.

Simplified example:

```java
if (a<5)
{ a++;}
if (a>=5 && a<10)
{ a+=5;}
if (a>=10)
{ a+=10;}
```

This seems like implementing a single increment by different values, depending on the initial value.
But think through what happens for `a` starting off as 4.
The first condition triggers, incrementing to 5.
The second condition triggers, incrementing to 10.
The third condition triggers, incrementing to 20.

In contrast to that.

```java
if (a<5)
{ a++;}
else if (a>=5 && a<10)
{ a+=5;}
else if (a>=10)
{ a+=10;}
```

Starting with 4, `a` will only be incremented once, by 1, to 5, but the second condition does not get checked, because of the `else`.